# Seeking topographical data for northern Taiwan to make sense of peak-to-peak photos in 3D?

Tags: data-request, geospatial

I've been hiking in the mountains around the Taipei/Keelung area for years and have lots of photos of distant peaks from other peaks. I'd like to build a 3D surface mesh of the topography so I can play with it in Python and maybe [Blender](https://blender.stackexchange.com/) to make sense of it (personal use).

Are there publicly available topographical data for northern Taiwan that I could use to do this?

Ideally in some tabular format so that I wouldn't have to install stand-alone software in order to use. A python package is no problem. I don't mind massaging or interpolating from one coordinate system to another myself, as long as it's not too complicated.

I'm looking for resolution of something of the order of 5 meters vertically an 10 horizontally, but there's no specific hard requirement.

Comment: @PolyGeo this wasn't as difficult as I'd imagined!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**update:** There is an extensive list of open sources of topographical data of Earth provided in [this thorough answer](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/a/16536/6031).

---

This will do the trick for me, although my application is non-critical.

1. go to US Global Data Explorer https://gdex.cr.usgs.gov/gdex/
2. create a login ID and sign in
3. select [NASA SRTM 1 arcsec](https://lpdaac.usgs.gov/node/527) on the right side (works for much of the Earth covered by the Space Shuttle's orbit, but not the poles, and has inaccuracies and holes)
4. select ROI with one of the options in the toolbar (click [User Guide](https://lpdaac.usgs.gov/sites/default/files/public/get_data/docs/GDExUserGuide.pdf))
5. download in GeoTIFF or ASCII format
6. click `metadata` for info scale and other information, see the first six lines in the ASCII file as well.
7. this height data is referenced to the WGS84 ellipsoid.
8. have fun!

[image]

[image]